# How many equivalence classes are there in this closeness relation on sequences?

Tags: cardinals, equivalence-relations

I had been watching a [pop-math video](https://youtu.be/aDOP0XynAzA?t=3m42s) and I noticed that they made the following assumption.

> Let $\Omega$ be the set of sequences on $\{ 0, 1\}$. Call two
>   sequences $t_1, t_2 \in \Omega$ *close* if they differ at finitely
>   many places.
>
> Then, there are only countably many equivalence classes of the
>   closeness relation.

How do I show this?

Comment: Not clear when they made that assumption (although I didn't watch the whole video, just that segment) and I don't think it's true.

Comment: The cardinality of each equivalence class is countable, which means the *number* of equivalence classes is uncountable (it has cardinality equal to the continuum).

Answer (score 0):

There are uncountably many equivalence classes. Observe that there are only a countable number of elements in each equivalence class, so if there were a countable number of equivalance classes then a countable union of countable sets would be uncountable.